# Degrees of factors of polynomial $f(x)=x^q-(ax^2+bx+c)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I’m facing the problem of factoring polynomials of type $f(x)=x^q-(ax^2+bx+c)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ and the degrees of factors seem to be quite special. For example, according to my experimental results done by [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/), there are only 24 kinds of factorizations of different degrees appearing when I factor 100 random such polynomials in $F_{81}[x]$ and factors of degrees {5, 20, 56} appear 5 times, factors of degrees {1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 25, 32} appear 5 times, factors of degrees {1, 1, 2, 3, 8 ,66} appear 8 times, … . What is the cause of this phenomenon? There are papers concerning the factorization of $f(x)=x^q-(bx+c)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ like http://dml.cz/dmlcz/126360, but I cannot find a suitable one for my type.

Here's the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167837/degrees-of-factors-of-polynomial-fx-xq-ax2bxc-in-mathbbf-qx/167842#167842) at MO for the same question.

Comment: Please don't crosspost here and at MO without telling. Adding a link to both questions is preferred. As a courtesy to avoid duplication of efforts. No harm done this time though.

Comment: The MO version of the question gave the link here from the beginning, but yes it should have gone both ways (and better yet to choose just one at first).

Comment: Now I understand why I should post at only one of the two sites: it is inconvenient to keep both of them updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answered on **mathoverflow**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167837):
the individual degree patterns don't have much structure, and the repetitions
occur because over a field of $q=p^f$ elements there are only about $q/f$
distinct choies of $f$ after accounting for translation, scaling, and
field automorphism (so for example $q=81$ yields about $20$ so we expect
each pattern to appear about $100/20=5$ times as observed).